# How to edit/update arraylist values in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, element, edit

I am completely new to c#, so please help me with the following problem.

I have an array list with some string elements.I want to edit/update a particular element at a particular index.

Can anyone please tell me a method, other than removing and then adding the edited element at the specific index?

Please find my try below[Changed the first element from "Black" to "Grey"]

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(){ "Black", "White", "Red"};

al.RemoveAt(0);

al.Insert(0,"Grey");
```

Comment: Why would you ever use `ArrayList` anyway? It's deprecated in favour of the much better `List<T>`

Comment: Just for learning purpose, as i told i am new to C#. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(){ "Black", "White", "Red"};
al[0] = "Grey";
```

Comment: Thank you, Never had a thought in this way,

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayList` type has an indexer you can use.

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList { "Black", "White", "Red"};

al[0] = "Grey";
```

For more information on indexers see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/